# About groups and closed subsets of the group.

Tags: group-theory

Is it true any subset  $H$ of a group $G$ that includes $\{e\}$ ( and the number of elements in  $H$ is  less the number of element in $G$) and  $H$ is also closed by the operation of the group $G$; then $H$ is a subgroup of $G$?

Comment: So we already have that the subset includes $e$ and is closed under the operation.  So the question is really whether this subset has inverses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We already have the fact that the subset includes the identity and is closed under the operation.  We only need to establish the existence of inverses.

This isn't so bad if our group is finite.  Consider any $h \in H$ and start taking powers.  In $G$, $\{h^n : n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ forms a cyclic subgroup.  Since $H$ is closed under the operation, this subgroup is indeed entirely contained in $H$.  Every element of a finite group must have finite order by the pidgeonhole principle $\Longrightarrow$ $h^k = e$ for some $k$.  Given this, what is the inverse of $h$?

Now what if $G$ was an infinite group?  As Thomas has stated, look to $\mathbb{Z}$ for some inspiration.

Comment: This works even if $G$ is infinite, as long as $H$ is finite.

Answer (score 0):

For finite groups this is true. Can you give a proof?

For infinite groups this is not necessarily true. Construct some subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ where this is not true.

Comment: Well, what would "having less element" mean in the second case, **if** $\;H\;$ is not finite? Or, *at least*, with cardinality less than $\;|G|\;$ ?

Comment: Well you really need that $H$ is finite, not that it has a cardinality strictly less than $G$.

Comment: exactly my point...

Comment: I guess we agree.